# Click-To-Copy on a Collapsible Definition List issue

Tags: list, definition

I have a "collapsible" definition list.

For each item of the list, I have added a Click-To-Copy button to the definition term  for it to copy the paragraph text of each term .

The problem is that everytime I click on the Click-To-Copy button, it automatically expands (or collapses) the paragraph, and I do not want it to do that.
I want the paragraph to be expanded (or collapsed) only when I click on the text of the definition term, but not when I click on the button within the definition term element.

```js
/* Collapsible Definition List usando jQuery */
(function( $ ){
$.fn.collapsible_definition_list = function() {
   return this.each(function(){  
  $(this).find('dd').hide().end().find('dt').addClass("more").bind({
   click: function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("more less");
    $(this).nextAll().each(function(){
     if($(this).is('dt')){
      return false;
     }
     $(this).slideToggle();
    });   
   }
  }); 
   });  
};
})( jQuery );

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.collapsible').collapsible_definition_list();
});

/* Here is the code for the click to copy: */
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<textarea>");
  var brRegex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).html().replace(brRegex, "\r\n")).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="collapsible">
  <dt><button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Click to Copy</button> Item 1</dt>
  <dd id="p1">Test text 1.<br>This is paragraph  #1</dd>

  <dt><button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p2')">Click to Copy</button> Item 2</dt>
  <dd id="p2">Test text 2.<br>This is paragraph  #2</dd>
  
  <dt><button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p3')">Click to Copy</button> Item 3</dt>
  <dd id="p3">Test text 3.<br>This is paragraph  #3</dd>
</dl>
```

What can I do so that clicking on the click-to-copy button does not activate the collapse/expand feature of the definition term element?

(just in case, be nice with me if I am doing something incorrectly... I've done this empirically)

Comment: Clicking on click-to-copy button should only copy the text to clipboard, right? But is there any situation where doing something only caused the collapse/expand feature?

Comment: @Andreas yes, clicking on the click-to-copy button that is located within the definition term <dt> should only copy the text that is located within the <dd>.

Clicking on the text of the definition term <dt> should expand the <dd>